# Bigdecimal low value

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have really low values stored in a mysql db, something like that:

```
0.00000070
0.00000097
```

I'm using spring boot to serve this values as a rest api, my model is mapped like this:

```
public class Account extends BaseEntity {   

    @Column(name = "VALUATION", precision = 15, scale = 8)
    @JsonView({ ViewsUtil.Ticker.class, ViewsUtil.Chart.class })
    @Setter @Getter
    private BigDecimal valuation;

    // others fields
```

In the db it's stored correctly, like i showed up, but to display, it's showing just like this:

```
{
   "valuation": 9.7e-7
}
```

There's a way to display like it's stored?

Thanks

---- EDIT

Changed my model to this

```
    @Column(name = "VALUATION", precision = 15, scale = 8)
    @JsonView({ ViewsUtil.Ticker.class, ViewsUtil.Chart.class })
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LowValueDeserializer.class)
    @Setter @Getter
    private BigDecimal valuation;
```

And my custom deserializer like this:

```
@JsonComponent
public class LowValueDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println(parser.getDecimalValue());

        return parser.getDecimalValue().toPlainString();
    }
}
```

The system out is never invoked and the result still the same.

Comment: See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-features: look for WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN

Comment: You want to format the BigDecimal for display.  This is a duplicate even though the format you want differs from the one used in the duplicated post.

Comment: @DwB Is there any advantage of using `String.format()` like in the dupe over `.toPlainString()`? Should be much better for what OP wants

Comment: Read my first comment for how to solve this "issue". Regarding your last edit: you won't solve a JSON **serialization** problem (how the BigDecimal is serialized to a JSON value) by using a custom **deserializer** (which is supposed to transform a JSON value to a BigDecimal).

Comment: @JBNizet Used your suggestion and works like a charm ! thank you

Comment: @c0nf1ck you're welcome.

Comment: Please don't append _solved_ to the title or post answers as updates to the question. If the answer is different to any of the answers on the duplicate consider posting it there. Thank you.

Comment: @baao toPlainString is fine if the OP wants no formatting, which does not appear to be the case.  write a test and see if you get 0.00000070 or 0.0000007 via toPlainString.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** 
As *JB Nizet* says in his comment, you must use:

> WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN

Since **Jackson 2.2** the `WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN` is available under the **Datatype-specific serialization** and in **default** set as `false`.

You can set it to `true` with the method `enable()` from `ObjectMapper`, like the following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN);
```

---

At the point you convert the **BigDecimal** to **String**, you must use the `.toPlainString()` method, like the following:

```
String theWholeNumber = YourBigDecimalNumber.toPlainString();
```

---

I think your problem is, that the value is shown with exponents in your **JSON-String**. I think it's not a problem, because you use the same model on client and server side (hopefully). If you want to work with it, it is not necessary to change the format. Only, if you want to display it, you need to convert it to **String** with the `.toPlainString()` method.

Comment: Yes i tried this, using @JsonDeserialize, but the method is never invoked

Comment: edited my post and add the code that i said